# When does Dojo need the args variable?

Tags: javascript, ajax, frameworks, dojo

You have to pass the args variable to the anonymous function, but the anonymous function does not visibly need the args variable, so you have to memorize when Dojo needs the args variable, but the Dojo help page doesn't say! So, when does Dojo need the args variable?

```
var init = function(){
var contentNode = dojo.byId("content");
dojo.xhrGet({
    url: "js/sample.txt",
    handleAs: "text",
    load: function(data,args){
    // fade out the node we're modifying
    dojo.fadeOut({
        node: contentNode,
        onEnd: function(){
        // set the data, fade it back in
        contentNode.innerHTML = data; 
        dojo.fadeIn({ node: contentNode }).play();    
        }
    }).play();
    },
    // if any error occurs, it goes here:
    error: function(error,args){
    console.warn("error!",error);
    }
});
}; 
dojo.addOnLoad(init);
```

Comment: You have to be more explicit. Paste some code.

Comment: I pasted some code. I'm wondering if it's going to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clarify: you are referring to the `args` argument you have in your code sample that is part of the function definitions for the `load` and `error` callbacks:

You only need the `args` variable if you need to use it. Dojo itself does not need it. Normally you should not need it. The first argument should be the result you are looking for.

However, if you need to access the raw `XMLHttpRequest` object, then `args.xhr` will hold it.

Similarly, if you want access to the original object you passed to `dojo.xhrGet` (because you stored some sort of state on it), you can get it at `args.args` (for this reason, I normally name that argument `ioArgs`, so it would then be `ioArgs.args`).